# R shiny download renderText ouput

Tags: r, shiny

In my app I'm calculating monthly mortgage payments.
I would like to download the resulting calculation.
Please suggest how.
Here is a code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)




# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Awesome Mortgage Calculator"),
    themeSelector(),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
      
        sidebarPanel(
          
          
            sliderInput("years",
                        "Years of payment:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 30,
                        value = 20),
            autonumericInput(
              inputId = "amount", 
              label = "Loan amount (CZK):", 
              value = 5000000, 
              currencySymbolPlacement = "p",
              decimalPlaces = 0,
              digitGroupSeparator = ",",
              decimalCharacter = "."
            ),
            numericInput("rate",
                         "Interest rate (%):",
                         value = 3,
                         min = 0,
                         max = 20,
                         step = .1
                         ),
            
            checkboxInput("amesome", 
                          label = "Are you awesome?",
                          value = FALSE
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
              condition = "input.amesome",
              sliderInput("awsome_scale", 
                          label = "How awesome are you?",
                          min = 0, 
                          max = 100, 
                          value = 50
              ),
              actionButton("awesome_button", "Who is awesome?"),
              actionButton("awesome_button2", "Who is awesome?")
            )
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            type = "tabs",
            
            tabPanel(
              title = "Calculator",
              tags$h3("Your monthly payment:"),
              textOutput("result"),
              tags$br(),
              tags$h5("Download result"),
              downloadButton("download_data")
              ),
            tabPanel(
              title = "Table",
              tableOutput("table")
            ),
            tabPanel(
              title = "Graph",
              plotOutput("plot")
            
            )
            
          )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$result <- renderText({
      
  
     # M = P*(r*(1 + r)n)/((1 + r)n - 1)
     
      
      amnt <- input$amount
      rt <- input$rate/100/12
      pmnts <- input$years*12
      
      res <- amnt*rt*(1+rt)**pmnts/((1+rt)**pmnts-1)
      
      calc_out <- paste(format(round(res, digits = 1), big.mark = ","), "CZK", sep = " ")
      calc_out
      
    })
    

    
    output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("result", ".csv", sep = "")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        writeLines(paste("calc_out", collapse = ", "), file)
      }
    )
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please suggest how to export the resulting calculation!
I think I need to store the resulting calculation somehow. I tried it with calc_out variable, but I cannot access.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `reactive()` for calculation and use that for `output$result` and in `downloadHandler()`:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  # reactive for calculation
  cal_out <- reactive({
    # M = P*(r*(1 + r)n)/((1 + r)n - 1)
    amnt <- input$amount
    rt <- input$rate/100/12
    pmnts <- input$years*12
    
    res <- amnt*rt*(1+rt)**pmnts/((1+rt)**pmnts-1)
    
    paste(format(round(res, digits = 1), big.mark = ","), "CZK", sep = " ")
  })

  # make sure to use paranthesis when getting reactive value, i.e. cal_out()
  output$result <- renderText(cal_out())

  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "result.txt"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      writeLines(cal_out(), file)
    }
  )
}
```